# React Array Not retaining Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to create li items from arrays. Ive tried two approaches.

1. Traditional arrray.
2. useState.

on submitting after every new input, the useState seem to retain data, but the former doesnt. The useState seem to resolve the problem but is there a  reason the former doesnt work and the latter works?

```
  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [myArray, setArray] = useState([]);
  const toDoList = [];

  function inputCapture(event) {
    const a = event.target.value;
    setInput(a);
  }

  function addToList() {
    myArray.push(input);
    toDoList.push(input)
    console.log(myArray, toDoList);
  }
```

Comment: The "traditional" array doesn't exist anymore when the render function has finished running. The next time it runs you create a new, empty array. This is exactly why useState exists, otherwise it wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear ,but you can check this solution

```
const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [myArray, setArray] = useState([]);
  const [todoList,setTodoList] = useState[];

  function inputCapture(event) {
    const a = event.target.value;
    setInput(a);
  }

  function addToList() {
    setArray([...myArray,input]);
    set([...toDoList,input])
    console.log(myArray, toDoList);
  }
```